# Calculate average and standard deviation per 5 rows in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, average

I have a dataframe such as:

```
A
27.00   
18.00
15.00
7.50
5.00
4.00
3.00
1.50
1.00
```

now I want to calculate average and standard deviation per 5 rows from bottom to top and set it at a above row as an additional column such as:

```
A       B(avg)  C(standard deviation)
27.00   9.90    6.24899992
18.00   6.90    4.827007354
15.00   4.20    2.252776065
7.50    2.90    1.673320053
5.00        
4.00        
3.00        
1.50        
1.00
```

9.90 = average-4.00, 5.00, 7.50, 15.00, 18.00

6.24899992 = standard deviation-4.00, 5.00, 7.50, 15.00, 18.00

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use rolling and shift a result 5 row up

```
df[['B','С']] = df.rolling(5)['A'].agg(('mean','std')).shift(-5)
```

Comment: This code return this:ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Comment: It means you already have columns B and C in df. `df.drop(columns=['B','C'])` before

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `.rolling()` combined with `.mean()` and with `.std()`:

```
df['B'] = df['A'].rolling(5).mean()
df['C'] = df['A'].rolling(5).std()
```

Edit:

`.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)` for each column to bring it to the top row.

Comment: your code return 14.5 in column B-row0, but the value I want to return is 9.9

Comment: average-4.00, 5.00, 7.50, 15.00, 18.00 in row0

Comment: For the first five rows the average is: `(27 + 18 + 15 + 7.5 + 5) / 5 = 14.5`.

Comment: But I want to average-4.00, 5.00, 7.50, 15.00, 18.00 in row0

Comment: Please clarify your question. Why do you want to start counting at the bottom and not take the first row into account?